# Crash with loadNibNamed, works in one project but not another

Tags: ios, objective-c

so i have a nib that i've loaded successfully in a test project using the line

```
NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FolderViewer" owner:nil options:nil];
```

the project is literally a new project with just the files added and that line in the default viewcontroller, and it loads fine.

but in another project of mine (where im actually trying to use it) it causes a crash with no useful error, just a SIGABRT.

i've checked in the projects build phases that the .xib file is actually included properly in the copy bundle resources (and spelled correctly)

i've fiddled around with the autolayout settings (which it does need, the project is set to 6.1 and up).

the nib has nothing attached to the files owner outlet (hence `owner:nil`)

and im stumped at what else could be causing the loading of the nib to cause a crash. the only difference i can think of is that in the test project the viewcontroller is loaded via storyboard, while in this project, the nib is being loaded within another nib.. but that surely shouldnt make a difference on that line i posted above.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this crash is welcome

Answer (score 0):

ok it was a silly mistake, (always is when the problem seems really weird). when i copied the files there was a file in this project with the same name as one of the tablecells in the nib already so i renamed it, but in doing so the connections for the tablecell in the nib were then pointing to the wrong file, slipped my mind to change where the outlets were pointing (derp)